# How can I refactor this C# code below?

Tags: c#, button, textbox, refactoring

I have 12 buttons in my Form1, and each button has a textbox next to it. The button event calls a method called dialogueOpen which handles getting the an object from form2 and placing a string value in a textbox.

How can I place the value returned in a textbox depending on what button the user clicked on? So if it is button1 a user clicked on, then the text returned should be placed in textbox1 and if it is button2 the user clicked on then the text returned should be placed in textbox2. The point is avoid using a string name to check as the buttons can all be called "browse".

Right now my code below does that but it is quite repetitive is there is a better of doing this?

```
    private void dailogueOpen(String btnName)
    {
        if (listBox1.SelectedItem == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Select a form");
        }
        else
        {
            var selectedItem = (FormItems)listBox1.SelectedItem;
            var form2result = new Form2(myDataSet, selectedItem);
            var resulOfForm2 = form2result.ShowDialog();

            if (resulOfForm2 == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                switch (btnName)
                {
                    case "btn1":
                        textBox1.Text = form2result.getValue();
                        break;
                    case "btn2":
                        textBox2.Text = form2result.getValue();
                        break;
                    case "btn3":
                        textBox3.Text = form2result.getValue();
                        break;
                    case "btn4":
                        textBox4.Text = form2result.getValue();
                        break;
                    case "btn5":
                        textBox5.Text = form2result.getValue();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String name = "btn1";
        dailogueOpen(name);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String name = "btn2";
        dailogueOpen(name);
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String name = "btn3";
        dailogueOpen(name);
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String name = "btn4";
        dailogueOpen(name);
    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String name = "btn5";
        dailogueOpen(name);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I just noticed your event handlers. More refactoring ensues:

Yes, there is. You need to somehow associate textboxes to buttons. For example, create a dictionary like so:

```
Dictionary<Button, TextBox> _dict;

_dict[button1] = textBox1;
_dict[button2] = textBox2; 
...
```

Use one event handler for all events:

```
private void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dialogeOpen((Button)sender);
}
```

Change `dialogueOpen` to accept a Button instead of a string and

```
 _dict[btn].Text = form2Result.getValue();
```

Comment: will this work if all the button's text says "browse" for instance. will dict[button1] still work ?

Comment: Yes, note I'm referring to the button's name in C#, not its text.

Comment: +1 for being the most consise answer (in terms of code) so far while not doing anything odd.

Comment: @zmbq sorry to bother you again, your solution is probably the best ... but just to clarify things... if i add your first section of code in my constructor where do i add that last section of code which is _dict[btn].Text = form2Result.getValue();

Comment: The last section replaces the repeated if statements in your `dialogueOpen` method.

Answer (score 1):

1 You use the `same delegate` on all `button`

`Nota (Thank's to Marty) :` When You're in the Form Designer, select all buttons, and then assing then "Generic_Click" for all of them, or you can use code below.

```
this.btn1.Click += new System.EventHandler(Generic_Click); //the same delegate
this.btn2.Click += new System.EventHandler(Generic_Click);
this.btn3.Click += new System.EventHandler(Generic_Click);
....


private void Generic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var control = (Button)sender;
     if(  control.Name == "btn1")
     {
        ....
     }
     else if(  control.Name == "btn2")
     {
        ....
     }
     else if(  control.Name == "btn3")
     {
        ....
     }


}
```

Comment: When You're in the Form Designer, select all buttons, and then assing then "Generic_Click" for all of them.

Comment: Thank's Marty for your complement , you are nice

Comment: Probably better to do just one cast rather than casting in every single if statement.

Answer (score 1):

replace your eventhandlers to

```
private void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as Button;
    if (button == null) return;
    String name = button.Text;// Tag, name etc
    dailogueOpen(name);
}
```

Comment: this means ill still have to check what name is passed into dailogueOpen, what if all the buttons are named "browse" ?

Comment: i don't know specific of your application, therefore wrote in comment alternative prorepties

Answer (score 1):

I would first use just one event handler for the buttons, it would look like this:

```
protected void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button clickedButton = (Button) sender;
    string selectedId = clickedButton.ID;
    string[] idParameters = selectedId.Split('_');
    string textBoxId = "textbox" + idParameters[1];
    dailogueOpen(textBoxId);
}
```

What I did here is use a pattern for the names of the textboxes, so for instance if you have buttons with ids like: button_1 ,button_2, ..., button_n, you can infer what the corresponding textbox is.

If you click button_1, by spliting its id you'll know that its corresponding textbox is the one whose id is textbox1.

Then the dialogueOpen function would look like this:

```
private void dailogueOpen(string textBoxId)
{
    if (listBox1.SelectedItem == null)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Please Select a form");
    }
    else
    {
        var selectedItem = (FormItems)listBox1.SelectedItem;
        var form2result = new Form2(myDataSet, selectedItem);
        var resulOfForm2 = form2result.ShowDialog();
        if (resulOfForm2 == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            TextBox textBox = (TextBox)this.Form.FindControl("MainContent").FindControl(textBoxId);
            textBox.Text = resulOfForm2.getValue();
    }
}
```

Where MainContent is the id of container where the textboxes are.

All in all:

- I would use a pattern for button and texboxes id.
- According to the button being clicked I infer its corresponding texbox id.
- Then  find the texbox and update its value.

Answer (score 0):

You can have dictionary and one event method on all button clicks

```
Dictionary<Button, TextBox> dx = new Dictionary<Button, TextBox>;

private void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as Button;
    if (button == null) return;
    dx[button].Text = form2result.getValue();
}
```

and constructor like this:

```
public ClassName()
{
   dx.Add(button1, textBox1);
   dx.Add(button2, textBox2);
   dx.Add(button3, textBox3);
}
```

Comment: will this work if all the button's text says "browse" for instance. will dx still work ?

Comment: Yes, because buttons are different objects with different hash codes

Answer (score 0):

I think the first thing you can do is improve readability by removing the need for the switch statement:

```
private void dailogueOpen(TextBox textBox)
{
    if (listBox1.SelectedItem == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Select a form");
    }
    else
    {
        var selectedItem = (FormItems)listBox1.SelectedItem;
        var form2result = new Form2(myDataSet, selectedItem);
        var resulOfForm2 = form2result.ShowDialog();

        if (resulOfForm2 == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBox.Text = form2result.getValue();
        }
    }
}


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dailogueOpen(textBox1);
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dailogueOpen(textBox2);
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dailogueOpen(textBox3);
}

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dailogueOpen(textBox4);
}

private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dailogueOpen(textBox5);
}
```

This then gives you a reasonable method signature to introduce the dictionary (suggested by two other people) to map Button to TextBox, which would in turn allow you to use a single event handler (suggested by two other people) for all buttons.

Answer (score 0):

```
  private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Button button = sender as Button;
            if (button == null) return;
            String name = button.Text;// Tag, name etc


            dailogueOpen(name);
        }


     private void dailogueOpen(String btnName)
        {
            if (listBox1.SelectedItem == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Select a form");
            }
            else
            {
                var selectedItem = (FormItems)listBox1.SelectedItem;
                var form2result = new Form2(myDataSet, selectedItem);
                var resulOfForm2 = form2result.ShowDialog();

                if (resulOfForm2 == DialogResult.OK)
                { 
                   SetTxt(btnName,form2result.getValue());
                }
            }
    }



      private void SetTxt(string btnName, string value)
            {
                int lenght = "Button".Length;
                string index = btnName.Substring(lenght); //remove Button
                TextBox t = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find("textBox" + index, true)[0];

                if (t != null)
                    t.Text = value;
            }
```